# Select item from a ComboBox

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I have Access 2010 form which has a ComboBox `cmbSubTopic` which lists two columns (`SubTopicID` and `SubTopic`). The combo box is bound to a field containing `SubTopicID`. The `SubTopicID` column in the combo box is hidden, it only shows the `SubTopic`. When the user selects a `SubTopic` from the drop down the corresponding `SubTopicID` is stored in the table. I wrote some VBA code for the on load event of the form to look up the `SubTopicID` in the table and the corresponding `SubTopic` is selected in the ComboBox. My current code is something like this:

```
Set rsST = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSqlst)
For i = 0 To Me.cmbSubTopic.ListCount - 1
    If Me.cmbSubTopic.Column(0, i) = rsST.Fields("SubTopicID").Value Then
        Me.cmbSubTopic.SetFocus
        Me.cmbSubTopic.Selected(i) = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

This gives the error saying:

> The text you entered isn't an item in the list

I also tried using this:

```
Me.cmbSubTopic = Me.cmbSubTopic.Selected(i)
```

This selects the item in the ComboBox but it also writes the value of I in to the `ID` field of the table which I don't want.

Comment: Generally you have nothing to do for the combobox having a controlsource, as its value is that of the underlyng table field.

Comment: Is there a way I can block inserting the data into the table on the OnLoad event of the form and then allow insert on the AfterUpdate event of the combobox.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming the combo's first column, `SubTopicID`, is also its "bound column" property, that column's value is used as the combo's `.Value` property.  That means you only need to assign a value to `.Value` in order to select the matching combo row.

```vb
Me.cmbSubTopic.Value =  rsST.Fields("SubTopicID").Value
```

That approach is simple, but I'm uncertain whether it is the appropriate solution for your situation.  We don't know anything about your `rsST` recordset --- I presumed the `SubTopicID` field in the recordset's current row is the value you want selected in the combo.  If I misunderstood that point, we need to figure out something different.

If the combo is bound to a field in the form's record source, this suggestion would also change the stored value.  If you don't want that, "unbind" the combo --- in other words, make its *Control Source* property blank.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign ItemData(idx) to your combobox:

```
     'Change the combobox slection to the second item
     '(index starts with zero)

     cmb = cmb.ItemData(1)
```

Note that I have been working with MS Access 2007. The more current version might not allow this assignment anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 subs - one for passing text (SubTopic) and the second for ID (SubTopicId):

```
Public Sub SelectComboBoxItemByText(cmb As ComboBox, Value As String)
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler_
Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To cmb.ListCount - 1
        If cmb.Column(1, i) = Value Then
            cmb.SetFocus
            cmb.Selected(i) = True
            cmb.Text = Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
ExitProc_:
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler_:
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    Call LogError(Err, "basTools", "SelectComboBoxItemByText")
    Resume ExitProc_
    Resume ' use for debugging
End Sub

Public Sub SelectComboBoxItemById(cmb As ComboBox, Value As Integer)
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler_
Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To cmb.ListCount - 1
        If cmb.Column(0, i) = Value Then
            cmb.SetFocus
            cmb.Selected(i) = True
            cmb = Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
ExitProc_:
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler_:
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    Call LogError(Err, "basTools", "SelectComboBoxItemById")
    Resume ExitProc_
    Resume ' use for debugging
End Sub
```